# creating multidimension array with multiple coloumn in perl

Tags: perl

```
ID  Cat    
1   Car          
2   Education     
3   Mathematics   
4   Physics       
5   Astrophysics
```

Based on this list, I want to generate and access array in the following manner:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [cat] => car
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [cat] => Education
        )

      [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [cat] => Mathematics
        )   


)
```

and so on till end of array.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#ARRAYS-OF-HASHES

Answer (score 5):

A simple way to do this is to read your file, line-by-line, split each line into the id and category portions and use those to create an array of *hash references*:

```
use strict;
use warnings; 

use Data::Dumper;

my @categories;
while ( my $row = <DATA> ) {
   my ($id, $cat) = $row =~ m/(\d+)\s+(\w+)/;

   push @categories, { id => $id, cat => $cat };
}

print Dumper \@categories; 

__DATA__
1 Car
2 Education
3 Mathematics
4 Physics
5 Astrophysics
```

output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'cat' => 'Car',
            'id' => '1'
          },
          {
            'cat' => 'Education',
            'id' => '2'
          },
          {
            'cat' => 'Mathematics',
            'id' => '3'
          },
          {
            'cat' => 'Physics',
            'id' => '4'
          },
          {
            'cat' => 'Astrophysics',
            'id' => '5'
          }
        ];
```

If your file is anymore complex than this (e.g. has quoting) you should really use [`Text::CSV_XS`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS)

Comment: No i cant use Module Test::CSV_XS.Any other alternative

Comment: Good answer to a bad question...  I think @user762641 could benefit from reading https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perldsc.pod and eventually https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perllol.pod as well.

Comment: @user762641 There is no module in core that I know of that can parse CSV files. You will have to build your own.